# Submit a form with a link

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a form submission if LocalStorage exist (and it's values in input fields) by clicking a link which adds some additional values to some inputs (these do not need to be stored in LocalStorage).

If localStorage doesn't exist then do nothing just add additional values to some inputs from data- attributes of clicked link.

My code is:

```
<div id="links">
    <h3>Links</h3>
    <a href="#1" data-url="http://apple.com" data-name="My url">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#2" data-url="http://bbc.co.uk" data-name="My second url">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#3" data-url="http://google.com" data-name="My third url">Link 3</a>
</div>
<div id="form">
    <h3>Form</h3>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" size="25" value="">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" size="25" value="">
    <input type="text" name="fname" size="25" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="" value="">
</div>
```

And the jquery code is:

```
document.getElementById('name').value = localStorage.getItem("name");
document.getElementById('email').value = localStorage.getItem("email");

$('#links a').click(function () {
    $('#form').find('input[name="fname"]').val($(this).data('name'));
    $('#form').find('input[type="hidden"]').val($(this).data('url'));
    localStorage.setItem("name", document.getElementById('name').value);
    localStorage.setItem("email", document.getElementById('email').value);
});
```

I would like to have only one LocalStorage record with a string of Name and Email values. I really appreciate your help.

Please find my jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uhvja70q/2/

Comment: What is the issue!! Can you elaborate please??

Comment: I cannot putvalues of form fields: input[name="fname"] and input[type="hidden"] into one local storage

Comment: Like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/uhvja70q/4/)**?? Check `console` for details!

Comment: Thank you. Yes and I need to restore them into fields on the next load of the page

Comment: Ok!! Like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/uhvja70q/5/)** now??

Comment: Can I save data from inputs with id="name" and id="email" bit not input[name="fname"] and input[type="hidden"]

Comment: Quite unclear!! can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Sorry. I want to add to LocalStorage only values of inputs with IDs - Name, Email. And restore them on a next page load. Inputs with [name="fname"] and input[type="hidden"] not being stored in LocalStorage

Comment: You want to store values stored in Inputs with `[name="fname"] and input[type="hidden"]` too in localStorage?

Comment: No I don't want them to be stored. Thank you

Comment: The above demo doesn't store values of `input[name="fname"]` and `input[type="hidden"]` but only stores values of `name` and `email`. That's what you want right?

Answer (score 0):

If anybody needs a solution for a similar issue please find it here:

```
$('#links a').click(function () {
if (localStorage.getItem("values") === null) {
$('#form').find('input[name="fname"]').val($(this).data('name'));
$('#form').find('input[type="hidden"]').val($(this).data('url'));
} else {
$('#form').find('input[name="fname"]').val($(this).data('name'));
$('#form').find('input[type="hidden"]').val($(this).data('url'));
$('#submit').trigger('submit');
} 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zm9jbnzo/4/